# How do I fix an invalid /etc/sudoers file if root access is disabled?

Tags: sudo, root, raspberry-pi, sudoers, raspbmc

This pertains to my Raspberry Pi, on which I have Raspbmc installed. I do realize that there is a Raspberry Pi StackExchange site, but I figured I might get more eyes on this problem here.

The issue is that I modified `/etc/sudoers` in an attempt to grant `NOPASSWD` permissions to one of the users, but I guess somewhere along the way I borked up the file and now I'm getting the following error whenever I login/attempt to use `sudo`:

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 19
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I've found similar posts on [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi) as well as [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238943/changed-permissions-of-etc-sudoers-and-now-i-cant-sudo-su-root-root-log), but the problem is all the answers require a root password, and the [root account is disabled by default on Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/root-access/), and I obviously had not enabled it before attempting to change `/etc/sudoers`.

So my question is: how do I fix the file if I don't have root access enabled? Is it even possible?

Comment: Don't forget to use `visudo` next time for editing.

Answer (score 8):

You should still be able to boot up the Pi in Single User mode to get access to root.

Using another computer, modify `cmdline.txt` and add `single` to the end of the line
Then when you boot up the Pi from the SD card, it should automatically dump you to a root prompt which well allow you to update `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Unfortunately I need root access to be able to modify `/boot/cmdline.txt` :(

Comment: Hence *using another computer*

Comment: Raspberry Pi's hard drive is just SD card, so it is possible to plug it in via card reader to another computer and make all changes there without booting Pi in single mode.

Comment: @Nikolay Assuming the OP has another computer with Linux installed or has a Live Distro handy of course.

Comment: (Or Windows/OSX with VirtualBox; the "USB sharing" feature works well.) Though, `single` also asks for root password, so while it *does* allow logins to a locked or expired root account, it may still refuse access on occassion, so editing `/etc/sudoers` directly from the live system would be a bit easier and quicker.

Comment: My mistake, I somehow interpreted that as "using another computer" to SSH in, rather than inserting the SD card into another computer and modifying the file there. Thanks very much! :)

Comment: I tried this; I was able to modify `cmdline.txt` but that didn't automatically boot to a root prompt. I tried holding the Shift key and Esc key while booting, but neither of those keys worked either (and they were the only two keys I could find from googling that would help boot into a prompt). Did anyone have success with this answer?

Comment: Are you using RaspBMC with NOOBS or using raw RaspBMC ?

Comment: Just had this happen for a Raspberry Pi OS install, and it looks like just adding `single` to the end of the line is insufficient to get into the OS.

Answer (score 3):

After two days of research and browsing the web I have finally found a solution and been able to save my own Raspberry Pi system (not having to reformat the SD card and start from scratch)!

**NOTE:** This answer is pretty long. If you want to get to the actual solution quickly, I've added a header that you can scroll down to. I do recommend you read the whole answer though, as it may bring some insight into the differences between the Raspbian distribution and other Linux distributions as well as clarity to why a lot of the suggested solutions you find across the internet may not work on your Pi.

So normally, in a Linux environment, the quickest way to repair the broken sudo without even having to reboot is by using PolicyKit or the `pkexec` -command like this:

```
pkexec visudo
```

But on the Pi it most likely won't work, it will ask for the root password, but no password is accepted. (I mean, do you even remember setting a root password? Wait, you do? Then skip to the asterisk*.)

Some Linux distributions, for example Ubuntu, come with a recovery mode that can be accessed by holding down the shift-key during bootup and offers a user-friendly interface and allows one to be dropped into a root shell prompt where one could get access to fix the broken files. The Pi's Raspbian Linux distribution does not come with that kind of a recovery mode so that solution is not a solution for us. Yet the Pi does prompt you at bootup to hold down the shift-key to enter some kind of recovery mode and by entering the Pi's recovery mode or the NOOBS dialog we are surely on the right path towards repairing the broken sudo on our Pi.

Another common way of repairing sudo is by booting into single-user mode which gets you to a root shell prompt. The way you do this is by adding the word `single` to the end of the `cmdline.txt` -file on the system's boot partition. The next time your system boots up it will boot into single-user mode.

We can easily try this solution on our Pi because, conviniently, the Pi's recovery mode or the NOOBS dialog allows us to edit the `cmdline.txt` -file. In the recovery mode or the NOOBS dialog, by pressing the "Edit config" -icon you open up an editor that lets you edit two files, one of which is `cmdline.txt`. By pressing "OK" in the editor your changes are saved.

Unfortunately, when you boot into single-user mode or "rescue mode" on the Pi, you'll most likely get the following message:

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue.
```

This – as well as why the previously mentioned root password prompt didn't accept any passwords – is because Raspbian, by default, has no password set for the root account. This is not to be confused with a password that is nothing or that no password would be required. Raspbian, just like a handful of other Linux distributions (for example Debian which Raspbian is a derivate of), expects the user to operate as root through sudo and not through the account itself. Hence the root account is in the "lockdown" state that we are experiencing.

*If you set the root password yourself, for example through the command `sudo passwd root`, then you should be able to use the `pkexec` -command and boot into single-user mode. Note that when you do this, you need to use sudo, so this is obviously not a solution once sudo is broken, but I point this out because this is probably why some people found success in fixing their Pi's when applying the solutions suggesting the `pkexec` -command or single-user mode. These people had at some point gone and manually set a root password, unlocking their system's root account.

### The Solution

[This blog post](https://samx18.io/blog/2017/11/05/piBootIssue.html) explains how to do what we need to do. The steps are almost identical to the steps we took when trying to repair sudo through single-user mode. You don’t have to do all the cumbersome stuff the blog post mentions in order to edit the `cmdline.txt` -file, instead just do it in the NOOBS dialog. The key is to add `init=/bin/sh` to the end of the `cmdline.txt` -file. With that snippet added, the next time you boot up your Pi, you will be dropped into a root shell prompt.

Initially, the file system will be loaded in read-only mode, so before being able to edit anything, you’ll have to remount the root partition in read and write mode by executing the following command:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 /
```

Now you should be in a root shell prompt, where you can freely edit any file, including the broken sudo files.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to boot up another OS on a LiveDVD or LiveUSB (ideally a LiveUSB, and ideally a Linux OS) then mount the disc and manually change the file. I've done similar things before and fixed it in this manner. All of your files will be visible and editable from the Live system. Unless you've encrypted the drive; that makes things a bit more complicated.

Let me know if you have questions and I'll edit this answer - I'm not sure how comfortable you might be with setting up a live USB, but it's not very hard.